# Move android's code to native code

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, native

I'm new on jni and I'm trying  to develop an Android application that support native code. Currently I'm trying to move a piece of code used for accessing the battery temperature from java layer to native one.

The java code is:

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = this.getBaseContext().registerReceiver(null, ifilter);
int temperature = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE,-1);
```

While what I wrote for the native part is:

```
jclass intentFilterClass = (*env)->FindClass(env,"android/content/IntentFilter");
jclass intentClass = (*env)->FindClass(env,"android/content/Intent");
jclass ContextClass = (*env)->FindClass(env,"android/content/Context");
jclass ContextWrapperClass = (*env)->FindClass(env,"android/content/ContextWrapper");

jclass activityThread = (*env)->FindClass(env,"android/app/ActivityThread");
jmethodID currentActivityThread = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env,activityThread, "currentActivityThread", "()Landroid/app/ActivityThread;");
jobject at = (*env)->CallStaticObjectMethod(env,activityThread, currentActivityThread);

jmethodID getApplication = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,activityThread, "getApplication", "()Landroid/app/Application;");
jobject context = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env,at, getApplication);
if (context == NULL){
    LOGE("TEST ", " context is null");  
}

jmethodID constructorIntentFilter = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,intentFilterClass,"<init>","()V");
jobject IntentFilterObject = (*env)->NewObject(env,intentFilterClass,constructorIntentFilter,"android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED");
if (IntentFilterObject == NULL){
     LOGE("TEST ", "IntentFilterObject is null"); 
}

jmethodID registerReceiver = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, ContextClass,"registerReceiver","(Landroid/content/BroadcastReceiver;Landroid/content/IntentFilter;)Landroid/content/Intent;");
if (registerReceiver == NULL){
     LOGE("TEST ", " registerreceiver is null"); 
}

jobject IntentObject = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env,thiz,registerReceiver,NULL,IntentFilterObject);
if (IntentObject == NULL){
    LOGE("TEST ", "IntentObject is null"); 
}

jmethodID getIntExtra = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, intentClass,"getIntExtra","(Ljava/lang/String;I)I");
jint res = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env,IntentObject,getIntExtra,"temperature",-1);
```

Unfortunately the application crashes due to access to null pointer. In fact IntentObject is always null.

```
jobject IntentObject = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env,thiz,registerReceiver,NULL,IntentFilterObject);
```

Pidcat error log:

```
 art  F  art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: can't call int android.content.Intent.getIntExtra(java.lang.String, int) on null object
```

Comment: The signature for the `IntentFilter` constructor is wrong. You're getting the constructor that takes no arguments, but the one you want is the one that takes a `String` argument.

Comment: @pskink: That `NULL` matches what is done is the Java version (`registerReceiver(null, ifilter)`).

Comment: @Michael This makes sense but why the `IntentFilterObject` doesn't be null and there is no error? However I tried to change the signature `(Ljava/lang/String;)V` as you suggest but now the error is `accessed stale weak global reference; JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of deleted weak global reference`

Comment: _"but now the error is"_ Which reference, and which line of code is triggering that?

Comment: It seems to be te creation of the intentfilter object the line  `jobject IntentFilterObject = (*env)->NewObject(env,intentFilterClass,constructorIntentFilter,"android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED");` the constructorIntentFilter is not null the only things that i change is the signature of the consturctor

Comment: You can't pass a `char*` to something that expects a Java string. Use `NewString` or `NewStringUTF` to create a `jstring`.

Comment: Thanks, also the problem into `(*env)->CallIntMethod(env,IntentObject,getIntExtra,"temperature",-1);` was the char*, someone told me that there is no issue into using char*. You save my days man.